# awk: find the oldest and newest files by date

Tags: awk, files, directory, sort

I'm using an `awk script` to print the oldest and newest files created based on the date (the 6th 7th and 8th field).
my sample list, date in the format (YYYY/MM/DD):

```
file was created 2020/10/10 20:18:42 its name is output1
file was created on 2020/09/10 12:13:22 its name is foobar.awk
file was created on 2020/10/10 20:12:43 its name is output2
file was created on 2020/12/10 18:11:38 its name is foobar.bash
file was created on 2020/12/10 22:32:13 its name is output.txt
```

what it should look like:

```
Oldest file date :
2020/09/10 12:13:22
file name: foobar.awk

Newest file date :
2020/12/10 22:32:13
file name: output,txt
```

Note: I can only use `awk` I only want the oldest and newest files to be printed.
Also: I am NOT sorting my files, just simply printing the oldest and newest files.

Comment: This will never work well. You can't depend on the format of `ls` and it is generally a bad idea to parse the output of `ls`. See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs and [Why \*not\* parse \`ls\` (and what to do instead)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128985). Would you be open to other solutions, using something like `stat` instead of `ls`?

Comment: I've edited to the format to be used with the modified `ls -la --time-style`

Comment: This really won't work. Just make a file with a space in its name and try running your script. You really want to look at `stat` instead of `ls` for this.

Comment: `ls -ltr --time-style=full-iso | sed -n '2p;$p'`?

Comment: Likewise, since you "know about" `ls -t`, is there any reason you couldn't just do something like `ls -tr | awk 'NR==1{print} END{print}'`?

Comment: dont worry about piping in `ls` anymore, I made changes to the file format so that it can act like a regular text file.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming GNU awk:

```c
gawk '
    {created[$NF] = $5 " " $6}
    END {
        PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@val_str_asc"
        for (f in created) {print "oldest:", f, created[f]; break}
        PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@val_str_desc"
        for (f in created) {print "newest:", f, created[f]; break}
    }
' file
```

Ref: [Controlling Array Traversal](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Controlling-Array-Traversal.html), and [Using Predefined Array Scanning Orders with gawk](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Controlling-Scanning.html)

Answer (score 0):

Using `stat` to get the files and their modification times, `awk` to get min/max without sorting and format the output.

```bsh
stat -c "%Y %n" * | awk '
    min == "" || min > $1 {min = $1; fmin = substr($0, index($0, FS)+1)}
    max == "" || max < $1 {max = $1; fmax = substr($0, index($0, FS)+1)}
    END {
        form = "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S"
        printf "Oldest\nDate: %s\nFile: %s\n", strftime(form, min), fmin
        printf "Newest\nDate: %s\nFile: %s\n", strftime(form, max), fmax
    }'
```

Sample output:

```bsh
Oldest
Date: 2020/08/29 01:52:23
File: test.java
Newest
Date: 2020/10/12 06:52:21
File: test.sh
```

Notes:

- The above handles whitespaces into files, not newlines.
- I think awk strftime is GNU only